# bash scripts work fine when I run it from command line but not from cron

Tags: bash, cron, shell, shell-scripting

I have this bash script in runtests.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Library/WebServer/Documents/protractor_clipboards
protractor testscript.js
```

When I do this on terminal

```
./runtests.sh
```

But when I try to run it from crontab -e file I get this error

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/test/runtests.sh: line 3: protractor: command not found
```

I know that protractor is the command works but not sure whats going on

here is my crontab -e

```
*/5 * * * *  /Library/WebServer/Documents/test/runtests.sh
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `PATH` at the beginning of the script or use the full path to `protractor`. `cron` uses a default `PATH` while yours is likely modified by some `rc` file.

Comment: yep that was it ...got the paths exported and was working then

Comment: How did you export the path?